# Use wc on all subdirectories to count the sum of lines

Tags: linux, bash, text-files, console-application

How can I count all lines of all files in all subdirectories with `wc`?

```
cd mydir
wc -l *
..
11723 total
```

`man wc` suggests `wc -l --files0-from=-`, but I do not know how to generate the list of all files as `NUL-terminated  names`

```
find . -print | wc -l --files0-from=-
```

did not work.

Comment: `find . -name '*'|xargs wc -l`  may be helpful.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
find . -type f -print0 | wc -l --files0-from=-
```

If you only want the total number of lines, you could use

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

Comment: I used `find . -type f -print0 | wc -l --files0-from=-` it works fine and returns the sum at the end.

Comment: on mac, 1st gives: `wc: illegal option -- -`

Comment: On macOs 12.7, `wc` doesn't support the option `--files0-from` hence the error mentioned by @GeoffLangenderfer

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps you are looking for `exec` option of `find`.

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} \; | awk '{total += $1} END {print total}'
```

Comment: This is inefficient, as you're spawning a new `wc` for each file. `:-(`

Comment: Also this is totally broken if you happen to have a file like this: try `touch $'hello\n1000000'`. Surprise!

Answer (score 7):

To count all lines for specific file extension u can use ,

```
find . -name '*.fileextension' | xargs wc -l
```

if you want it on two or more different types of files u can put -o option

```
find . -name '*.fileextension1' -o -name '*.fileextension2' | xargs wc -l
```

Comment: This breaks on any file with whitespace or `\` in its name. See the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13728131/1081936) for how to use this approach correctly.

Comment: Love this solution even if it's apparently not sufficient in all cases. Worked for my purposes like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to use a recursive grep:

```
grep -hRc '' . | awk '{k+=$1}END{print k}'
```

The awk simply adds the numbers. The `grep` options used are:

```
   -c, --count
          Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching  lines
          for  each  input  file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see
          below), count non-matching lines.  (-c is specified by POSIX.)
   -h, --no-filename
          Suppress the prefixing of file names on  output.   This  is  the
          default  when there is only one file (or only standard input) to
          search.
   -R, --dereference-recursive
          Read all files under each directory,  recursively.   Follow  all
          symbolic links, unlike -r.
```

The `grep`, therefore, counts the number of lines matching anything (''), so essentially just counts the lines.

Answer (score 2):

Based on ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ's answer:

Example for counting lines of java code with formatting:

**one liner**

```
find . -name *.java -exec wc -l {} \; | awk '{printf ("%3d: %6d %s\n",NR,$1,$2); total += $1} END {printf ("     %6d\n",total)}'
```

**awk part:**

```
{ 
  printf ("%3d: %6d %s\n",NR,$1,$2); 
  total += $1
} 
END {
  printf ("     %6d\n",total)
}
```

**example result**

```
  1:    120 ./opencv/NativeLibrary.java
  2:     65 ./opencv/OsCheck.java
  3:      5 ./opencv/package-info.java
        190
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like

```
find ./ -type f | xargs wc -l | cut -c 1-8 | awk '{total += $1} END {print total}'
```

Comment: everything that is not a directory; in most cases will be the same as -type f

Comment: Except for block device nodes, character device nodes, named pipes, sockets, .... at least one of which will break the whole exercise... Best to stick to `-type f`...

Answer (score -2):

Bit late to the game here, but wouldn't this also work? `find . -type f | wc -l`

This counts all lines output by the 'find' command.  You can fine-tune the 'find' to show whatever you want.  I am using it to count the number of subdirectories, in one specific subdir, in deep tree:   `find ./*/*/*/*/*/*/TOC  -type d | wc -l` .  Output: `76435`.  (Just doing a find without all the intervening asterisks yielded an error.)

Comment: no, I think this would return something like the number of files. Not the sum of all lines in all files.

Comment: Ah, see that now.  Yep, nope it wouldn't.  :)