# Get total lines of file in multiple subdirectories within a directory (excluding black lines)

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, readline, subdirectory

I would like to have a script that goes through every single file in a directory (that includes sub directories) and return me the **total number of lines** in all files **excluding blank lines** and **excluding folders/files that have key words on them (log)**.

I currently have a line of code which returns me the total number of lines (including blank lines) in files of **a single directory** 'files'

```
cat /home/user/files/* | wc -l
```

Is there someway to implement so that I can call a code which can read through, for example:

```
- /home/user/files/*
- /home/user/files/files2/*
- /home/user/files/files2/files3/*
```

a bunch of directories (unknown number) and return me the total number of lines of all files (excluding blank lines) (and excluding folders/files that have key words on them (log)) found.

I'm currently using BASH to script but if there is an solution in python, I'm more than happy to use it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i've updated my question slightly, i would need the total  number of lines excluding blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding all the files in the directory recursively ( `-type f` flag to find).
Beware that this will print out binary files too, as does your current code.

```
find /home/user/files/ -type f -exec cat {} \; | wc -l
```

Edit: the `--files-from` solution given in [Use wc on all subdirectories to count the sum of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727917/use-wc-on-all-subdirectories-to-count-the-sum-of-lines) is more efficient, as linked to in the question comments

Comment: thanks for your edit. i was just about to ask you the differences between your solution and the solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727917/use-wc-on-all-subdirectories-to-count-the-sum-of-lines

Comment: apologies for unaccepting your answer, i've updated my question slightly as i forgot to add it in earlier - i would need it to return me the total number of lines (excluding blank lines)

Comment: No problems. Is it code files that you are counting? If so, there's quite a few lines of code (loc) analysis tools out there for use on continuous integration servers.

Comment: yes! i am essentially trying to count code. i'll have a look at them. would you also know how i could avoid counting certain folders/files with keywords on them? (i.e, 'log')

Comment: Depends on the tool. Some provide options to exclude, some don't. If it comes to it, pre-filter with `find/home/user/files/ -type f ! -path '*/log/*'`